# Linux: Ip forwarding or bridge?

Tags: linux, router, ip-forwarding

On a Ubuntu 8.04 I have two interfaces eth3 and eth4:avahi.

```
eth3 is in my local network with 192.168.178.63.
eth4:avahi has the ip 85.214.144.211.
```

From this box I can  `ping 85.214.144.212` successfully.

On a windows box in the same local network with ip `192.168.178.61` I want also be able to reach `85.214.144.212`. To achieve this I used the following steps:

1. On the windows machine I entered `192.168.178.63` as gateway.
2. On the Ubuntu I activated `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forwarding`

Now on the windows machine I can `ping 85.214.144.211` but not `ping 85.214.144.212`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason: 85.214.144.212 don't know route to 192.168.178.0/24 network.

1. Add route to 192.168.178.0/24 network on 85.214.144.212-box.

2. Use NAT on Ubuntu_8.04.

Comment: Thanks. How do you do 1. and 2.? Especially as the 212-box is a OpenVZ-guest on the 211-host

Comment: What is the default gateway of the 212 box?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what an OpenVZ-guest is, but if it is a host on the Internet then you will have to use network address translation (NAT) on your Ubuntu host because 192.168.x.y addresses are not routable beyond your local network.